# Creating a unique filename from a list of alphanumeric strings

Tags: uniqueidentifier, alphanumeric

I apologize for creating a similar thread to many that are out there now, but I mainly wanted to also get some insight on some methods.

I have a list of Strings (could be just 1 or over a 1000)
Format = XXX-XXXXX-XX where each one is alphanumeric

I am trying to generate a unique string (currently 18 in length but probably could be longer ensuring not to maximize file length or path length) that I could reproduce if I have that same list.  Order doesn't matter; although I may be interested if its easier to restrict the order as well.

My current Java code is follows (which failed today, hence why I am here):

```
public String createOutputFileName(ArrayList alInput, EnumFPFunction efpf, boolean pHeaders) {
    /* create file name based on input list */
    String sFileName = "";
    long partNum = 0;

    for (String sGPN : alInput) {
        sGPN = sGPN.replaceAll("-", ""); //remove dashes
        partNum += Long.parseLong(sGPN, 36);    //(base 36)
    }
    sFileName = Long.toString(partNum);
    if (sFileName.length() > 19) {
        sFileName.substring(0, 18); //Max length of 19
    }
    return alInput;
}
```

So obviously just adding them did not work out so well I found out (also think I should take last 18 digits and not first 18)

Are there any good methods out there (possibly CRC related) that would work?

To assist with my key creation:
The first 3 characters are almost always numeric and would probably have many duplicate (out of 100, there may only be 10 different starting numbers)
These characters are not allowed - I,O
There will never be a character then a number in the last two alphachar subset.

Comment: If you want your `substring(a,b)` to be length 19, then `b-a == 19`. Make it `substring(0,19) to make it max length of 19.

Comment: I just though that since periods are allowed in filenames [decimal point], using multiplication/division may yield more uniqueness.  Would that be true?

Comment: @glowcoder Nice catch, although my fault case would still occur.  Unfortunately 000-00000-001,000-00000-004 would be the same as 000-00000-002,000-00000-003

Comment: Granted that probably would not come up like that, but that is essentially how it occurred, but a little more complex with a list of ten and similar parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to GlowCoder's response, I have thought of another "decent one" that would work.

Instead of just adding the list in base 36, I would do two separate things to the same list.

In this case, since there is no way for negative or decimal numbers, adding every number and multiplying every number separately and concatenating these base36 number strings isn't a bad way either.

In my case, I would take the last nine digits of the added number and last nine of the multiplied number.  This would eliminate my previous errors and make it quite robust.  It obviously is still possible for errors once overflow starts occurring, but could also work in this case.  Extending the allowable string length would make it more robust as well.

Sample code:

```
    public String createOutputFileName(ArrayList alInput, EnumFPFunction efpf, boolean pHeaders) {
        /* create file name based on input list */
        String sFileName1 = "";
        String sFileName2 = "";

        long partNum1 = 0;  // Starting point for addition
        long partNum2 = 1;  // Starting point for multiplication

        for (String sGPN : alInput) {
            //remove dashes
            sGPN = sGPN.replaceAll("-", "");
            partNum1 += Long.parseLong(sGPN, 36);    //(base 36)
            partNum2 *= Long.parseLong(sGPN, 36);    //(base 36)
        }

        // Initial strings
        sFileName1 = "000000000" + Long.toString(partNum1, 36);   // base 36
        sFileName2 = "000000000" + Long.toString(partNum2, 36);   // base 36

        // Cropped strings
        sFileName1 = sFileName1.substring(sFileName1.length()-9, sFileName1.length());
        sFileName2 = sFileName2.substring(sFileName2.length()-9, sFileName2.length());

        return sFileName1 + sFileName2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the system time. Here's how you might do it in Java:

```
public String createOutputFileName() {
    long mills = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long nanos = System.nanoTime();
    return mills + " " + nanos;
}
```

If you want to add some information about the items and their part numbers, you can, of course!

======== EDIT: "What do I mean by batch object" =========

```
class Batch {

    ArrayList<Item> itemsToProcess;
    String inputFilename; // input to external process
    boolean processingFinished;

    public Batch(ArrayList<Item> itemsToProcess) {
        this.itemsToProcess = itemsToProcess;
        inputFilename = null;
        processingFinished = false;
    }

    public void processWithExternal() {
        if(inputFilename != null || processingFinished) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot initiate process more than once!");
        }
        String base = System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + System.nanoTime();
        this.inputFilename = base + "_input";

        writeItemsToFile();

        // however you build your process, do it here
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myProcess","myargs", inputFilename);

        p.start();
        p.waitFor();
        processingFinished = true;
    }

    private void writeItemsToFile() {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(inputFilename)));
        int flushcount = 0;
        for(Item item : itemsToProcess) {
            String output = item.getFileRepresentation();
            out.println(output);
            if(++flushcount % 10 == 0) out.flush();
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: That would be "random", which is not what I am aiming for.  But rather as close to it as possible and must be dependent on the list.  The reason I am doing this is I have to call an external function that takes about 30 seconds, and it saves its data to an output file that I give it.  So I am looking to see if I have already done it before so I know what file to check.

Comment: Honestly, that would be much better achieved by a `boolean` value internally that says "If this boolean is true, this batch has already been processed". If you don't have one already, extract this into a `Batch` object, with a list of items to process for the batch. (Hint: I work on an ERP system for a living :-D)

Comment: Can you explain more of what you mean by Batch Object?  And I believe I still run into the issue of trying to map a list to a single unique value.  For this, the best idea I can think of is to just pre-sort the list, then append the list to itself making a huge string and devide it by a some number to keep the decimal?

Comment: Thanks for the example/shell, I will take a look into it.  Seems to be no possible error involved, but more memory usage perhaps.  But I think that should be okay to handle in my application.  I'll try it out this week and post back with props or questions.

Comment: Sounds good. I wouldn't say no possible error, because... heh... there's always possible error! :P The additional usage wouldn't be much, you're looking at an extra String and an extra boolean (you already have that List, so that's no additional cost.) In fact, it might save you on memory if you are constructing this list more than once - here you could create and store once as opposed to multiple times.

Comment: i tried repping your insight, but my score is still too low.  I'll try to remember to come back when I finally reach 15 :)